# Getting Incorrect answer on Assembly Language Loop (Assembly 8086)

Tags: assembly, x86

I'm new to assembly language and I'm struggling to find out what is going on with this program I am writing . The goal of the program is for the user to enter a number between 0 and 9 . It then checks if this number is a multiple of 3 , if an incorrect character (i.e Z ) is entered it should simply put '**' next to the character and ask again for the user to enter a number. If a number is entered it is then converted from a ASCII character to a number and then divided .

Now the problem is when I enter a correct character(0-9) first the answer comes back correctly . Lets say I enter 3 it will say its a multiple , if I enter 4 first it will say its not a multiple which is correct . But as soon as I enter a incorrect character and it starts looping it doesn't give me the correct answer once I enter in a correct character . Please look at this code and see if anyone can help me .

HERE IS THE CODE:

```
    bits 16 
    org 0x100
    jmp main

    name db 'Assembly Program Divider','$',0dh,0ah
    prompt db 'Please enter a number (0 - 9): ','$',0dh,0ah
    invalid db 'Invalid Character','$',0dh,0ah
    is db 'Number is a multiple of 3','$',0dh,0ah
    isnot db 'Number is not a multiple of 3','$',0dh,0ah
    asteriks db '**','$',0dh,0ah

    cr_lf: 
    db 0dh,0ah,'$' ; carriage return and line feed

;Scroll and clear the screen and also change background and text color
    clr_scr:
    mov ax,0600h ; Scroll the entire screen
    mov bh,1Eh ; Colour: white to blue
    mov cx,00 ; From top left corner
    mov dx,184Fh ; To lower right corner
    int 10h ; BIOS interrupt
    nop
    ret

;Set the cursor position on the screen
    set_csr:
    mov ah,02 ; Set cursor
    mov bh,00 ; Screen number 0
    mov dx,0a00h ; row 10, column 0
    int 10h ; BIOS interrupt
    ret

;Display a message on the terminal
    disp_str:
    mov ah,09 ; Display message
    int 21h ; DOS interrupt
    ret

;Read a character from terminal
    read_chr:
    mov dx,cr_lf ; address of line feed
    call disp_str ; display line feed
    mov dx,prompt ; address of prompt
    call disp_str ; display prompt
    mov ah,01 ; get character from keyboard
    int 21h ; DOS system call
    cmp al,39h
    jg diss_invalid
    cmp al,30h
    jl diss_invalid
    ret

;Display a message for an invalid character entered
    diss_invalid:
    mov dx,asteriks ;address of asteriks to display next to character
    call disp_str ; display asteriks 
    call read_chr ; run the read character again untill correct character is entered

;Display message for when the number is a multiple of 3
    diss_is:
    mov dx,cr_lf ; address of line feed
    call disp_str ; display line feed
    mov dx,is
    mov ah,09 ; Display message
    int 21h ; DOS interrupt
    int 20h ; Terminate Program

;Display message for when the number is not a multiple of 3
    diss_isnot:
    mov dx,cr_lf ; address of line feed
    call disp_str ; display line feed
    mov dx,isnot
    mov ah,09 ; Display message
    int 21h ; DOS interrupt
    int 20h ; Terminate program

    str_to_num:
    mov dx, 0
    sub al,0    ; ASCII value converted to numeric value
    mov ah,0     ; AX = numeric value of digit
    add dx,dx    ; DX = 2 * original DX
    add ax,dx    ; AX = 2 * original DX + digit
    add dx,dx    ; DX = 4 * original DX
    add dx,dx    ; DX = 8 * original DX
    add dx,ax    ; DX = 10 * original DX + digit
    ret

    divide:
    mov ah,0 ; clear AH 
    mov dl,03h ; Divisor 3 in DL
    idiv dl ; integer division , remainder stored in AH
    cmp ah,0 ; compare the remainder to 0
    je diss_is ; if the reminder = 0 go to display is
    cmp ah,0 ; compare the remainder to 0
    jg diss_isnot ; if the reminder is not 0 go to display isnot

;Main program to be executed
    main:
    call clr_scr ; clear screen
    call set_csr ; set cursor
    mov dx,name ; address of name and student number
    call disp_str ; display name and student number
    call read_chr ; read character
    call str_to_num ; convert the character received to a number
    call divide ; divide the converted number by 3 and check if it has a remainder
    int 20h ; Terminate the program if all is successfull
```

Thanks in advance !!

Here is examples of what happens:

```
Please enter a number (0 - 9)j**
Please enter a number (0 - 9)k**
Please enter a number (0 - 9)7
Number is a multiple of 3

Please enter a number (0 - 9)j**
Please enter a number (0 - 9)k**
Please enter a number (0 - 9)8
Number is a multiple of 3

Please enter a number (0 - 9)j**
Please enter a number (0 - 9)k**
Please enter a number (0 - 9)3
Number is a multiple of 3

Please enter a number (0 - 9)7
Number is not a multiple of 3

Please enter a number (0 - 9)3
Number is a multiple of 3
```

Comment: It's very rare to get incorrect answer from CPU. I would rather suspect your code is not doing what you intended. That said, it's hard to follow your intention with the limited comments. Anyway just out of curiosity (without reading full code), what do you think the code `idiv dl 
cmp ah,0 
je diss_is 
cmp ah,0 
jg diss_isnot` does? Try to step one instruction at time in your head with instruction reference guide, very thoroughly.

Comment: And of course you don't have to wait for anyone on SO answering, just fire up the debugger, and check by yourself, where something unexpected happens in your code.

Comment: Also check this one `sub al,0    ; ASCII value --> numeric value` ... either the instruction, or the comment is not true.

Comment: Thanks for the reply , I will comment a bit more in my code , I can see how that can be confusing . What I think the code idiv dl cmp ah,0 je diss_is cmp ah,0 jg diss_isnot - it divides the number in ax (dividend) with the divisor in dl (where I moved the hex number 3 into) the remainder is then stored in ah . I then compare ah with 0 , when it is 0 there is no remainder and it must be a multiple of 3 . Assembly is really confusing to me I am not sure If I understand those concepts correctly . I apologize if I am incorrect . But thanks for the help :D

Comment: `doesn't give me the correct answer`... But what *does* it do, *exactly*?  I'm not going to go find a DOS emulator just to try your code in a debugger.  You should be able to do that and tell us what happens, then we can answer to explain *why* it happens.  Using a debugger to single-step instructions and look at registers will make learning asm 100 times easier.

Comment: Actually I think you tried to explain what happens, but it's not very clear.  Maybe copy/paste the text from your DOS window into another code block, so we can see the output.  But info from a debugger about where your code is going wrong would be better.  Your code is too large to be considered a [mcve]; we don't need the whole program, just a stripped down example that reproduces the problem.

Comment: @PeterCordes it's quite short code, so it's actually very easy to run it in head and see all the shortcomings of it (took me like 3min to run it all with all possibilities, when I was in mood), but there's kinda too many bugs to my taste, I would prefer to navigate OP to resolve these on his own. If I will be annoying enough to make him finally realize the debugger is actually the easier option, even better. ;)

Comment: Guys could you point me in the right direction on how the debugging works , i have started with assembly about 3 days ago and I am not sure how everything works at this stage , any help would really be appreciated . Or could you please point me in the direction of a website where I could find the correct procedure for the debugging etc. I'm sure debugging would actually solve my problem to see where I am going wrong. Thanks for the replies.

Comment: Well, I'm not sure what are current best debugger options for DOS, back in 1995 I did use Turbo Debugger from Borland, obtained trough University license. If you are using dosbox, it's possible to build special debug version of dosbox with internal debugger included, but I didn't try it myself. If you are using bochs x86 emulator, it has also built-in debugger. Otherwise just google, SO is not about opinions/best tool questions. BTW, you are doing quite excellent for 3 days. No need to apologize for being incorrect. It's just ASM is very unforgiving thing and you must be exact.

Comment: Another comment: while `cmp al,39h` is doing what you want, you should try whether your assembler support also ASCII literals, like `cmp al,'9'` ... It's easier to read your intent then even for people, who don't know ASCII code for `9` from head. The hexa formatting is very nifty when working with bit masks, or when you want to set particular byte(s) in word/dword value, but here the ASCII letter itself is better fit (if possible in your assembler).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So this could be wrong because I didn't test it but I’m thinking at the end of `diss_invalid` you call `read_chr` right? And when it returns it returns to the next instruction after it was called back under `diss_invalid`.... which isn’t what you meant right? So instead of calling `read_chr`, I would put a label in main after `call disp_str ; display name and student number` that you can jump to from `diss_invalid`. But that is just a temporary solution. A more permanent one would be to start commenting EVERYTHING and to get out a piece of paper and draw out what you think *should* happen, then check if the code you wrote does that. Try to modularize everything. Should read char really be sanitizing input or should that be a separate function? etc...

Comment: Thank you a lot . Appreciate your help :) , will start organizing my stuff better because then this won't happen .

Answer (score 1):

I will add to this answer based on your responses in comments...

First about the:

```
divide:
mov ah,0
mov dl,03h
idiv dl
cmp ah,0
je diss_is
cmp ah,0
jg diss_isnot
```

> it divides the number in ax (dividend) with the divisor in dl (where I moved the hex number 3 into) the remainder is then stored in ah . I then compare ah with 0 , when it is 0 there is no remainder and it must be a multiple of 3 .

Quite good, but let's nitpick, because CPU does too (well, it just follows your instructions literally, not caring about nitpicking, but it feels sometimes like it is).

**"the hex number 3 into"** - the number 3 is number 3. We have many possible forms how to express it, from common decimal format `3` used by many humans, trough similar hexadecimal format `03h` (in some assemblers also C-like `0x03` works, or even `$03`), binary `0b11`, octal `0q03` or `03`, trough less numeric ways, like Roman numbers `III`, or just some expression like `***` (count of stars). In the CPU I prefer to imagine it as 8 (16/32/..) wires, each having either current flowing trough it, or not. Each wire then represents single bit, composing the 8/16/32/.. bit number.

So it doesn't matter how you write that 3, if it's hexadecimal form `03h` or decimal `3`, it will set bits in `dl` as `00000011`.

You can easily think about that "hexa number 3" as 3, there's no benefit to have it in hexa in this particular case, actually as the task description was about division by 3, I would rather stick to decimal form even in the source code. You will get the feel, where hexadecimal form is simpler, over time.

**You then compare the remainder with zero**, when equal, you jump to `diss_is`. That's completely correct.

**But that's not all of the code**, and it's not covering all possible cases. When the remainder is not equal to zero (it's 1 or 2), what will happen? After `cmp ah,0` the flags will be set up, in the same way, as after `sub ah,0`. Both 1-0 and 2-0 will set the interesting flags in the same way: ZF=0, CF=0, SF=0, OF=0.

So `je diss_is` will not branch, and the execution will continue on the next `cmp ah,0`. But did the `je` change some flags? It didn't. So it's not needed to do the `cmp` again, you already have the result of it in the flags from the first one.

Then you do `jg diss_isnot`, which will branch for both `1` and `2`, but as you covered the "0 remainder" case with `je`, you can just `jmp diss_isnot` directly without any condition. Or move the code from `diss_isnot` under the `je`.

If there would be some additional code changing flags ahead of `jg`, making it possible to not branch, the code would re-enter the `main` by accident! Can't happen in your case, but don't write code in this way, use simpy `jmp` to avoid any confusion.

Actually you do **`call divide`** in the `main`, but you will never return from it, because both branches have their own `int 20h`. You could shorten your code a bit by sharing removing duplicities in code, like calling the cr_lf before test (just make sure you store `al` with number somewhere, stack should work well), or even displaying the result by the same code, just adjusting the `dx,<result_message_offset>` in the branch, and then using the same code to end `divide`. And `ret` from it, so exit is only in `main`.

... end of part 1 ...

Now look at that `sub al,0` ASCII conversion.

And finally check your code flow for non number char, how it will branch, and what will happen on stack. Keep commenting back, what you think the code does.

Comment: Thanks for the advice . I will look into all of the points that you have given me and check if I can adjust my code to be better , thanks for the help.